# Using np.linalg.lstsq to solve for multiple variables

Tags: python, least-squares

I was given data and made a matrix based on the equation needed for the data. I converted it to ln(A)=ln(a) + bln(W) +cln(H), where A,W,H are given to me for multiple different values. I need to make a matrix out of them and solve for a,b,c. I've been trying to do it based on the numpy book instructions but I keep getting errors. I think I must be putting some part of it in wrong.

the matrix is:

ln(1.86)        1  ln(70)  ln(170)
ln(1.88)     =  1  ln(75)  ln(165)
ln(1.92)        1  ln(77)  ln(175)
ln(etc)         1  ln(etc) ln(etc)

A             ln(a)   b       c

here's my code:

```
x=([1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1], [np.log(70), np.log(75), np.log(77), np.log(80), np.log(82), np.log(84), np.log(87), np.log(90)], [np.log(170), np.log(165), np.log(175), np.log(183), np.log(188), np.log(187), np.log(190), np.log(197)])

    #lna=np.array([1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1])
    #b=np.array([np.log(70), np.log(75), np.log(77), np.log(80), np.log(82), np.log(84), np.log(87), np.log(90)])
    #c=np.array([np.log(170), np.log(165), np.log(175), np.log(183), np.log(188), np.log(187), np.log(190), np.log(197)])

y=np.array([np.log(1.86), np.log(1.88), np.log(1.92), np.log(2.15), np.log(2.18), np.log(2.16), np.log(2.25), np.log(2.29)])

X = np.vstack([x, np.ones(len(x))]).T

lna,b,c=np.linalg.lstsq(X,y,rcond=None)[0]
print(lna,b,c)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really deep into your problem myself, however, after some play-around the following was obtained:

```
x = np.array(
    [
        (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
        np.log((70, 75, 77, 80, 82, 84, 87, 90)),
        np.log((170, 165, 175, 183, 188, 187, 190, 197))
    ]
)
y = np.log((1.86, 1.88, 1.92, 2.15, 2.18, 2.16, 2.25, 2.29))
X = np.vstack([x, np.ones(x.shape[1])]).T
```

The output coefficient vector has to have dimension of 4 due to, as I understand, the 3-rd degree polynomial implied, hence the `d` parameter is added

```
lna, b, c, d = np.linalg.lstsq(X, y, rcond=None)[0]
```

Hopefully, that is what you seek for.